# std::ofstream opens when debugging in debug configuration, but not when in release configuration (Visual Studio 2022)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, ofstream

Sorry for any poor formatting - this is my first time asking a question here.

I'm working on a project which involves writing some information to a file. When I run or debug the program in debug compiler configuration (Visual Studio 2022, Windows 10), everything works perfectly. However, when I run/debug it in the release configuration, the std::ofstream at line 447 fails, and the program is std::abort()'d by the check a few lines later. I can't figure out why this is happening, especially as it works in the debug configuration.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>

void write_to_file()
{
    wchar_t path[256];
    int path_terminus{ -1 };
    std::string str_path{};

    GetModuleFileName(NULL, path, 256);                             //finds the current path

    for (int i{}; (i < 256 && i != path_terminus); ++i)     //finds location of the end of the path within the string
    {
        if (path[i] == '\0')
        {
            path_terminus = i;
        }
    }

    for (int i{ 0 }; i < (path_terminus - 20); ++i)         //deletes the "\\harmonic.series.exe" from the end
    {
        str_path.push_back(path[i]);
    }

    str_path += "\\harmonic_series.txt";                    //adds the filename to the path (changed from .wav to .txt for ease of reproductibility)

    std::ofstream ofs(str_path, std::ios::binary);          //opens the filestream

    if (!ofs.is_open())
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to open the ofstream.\n\n";
        system("pause");
        std::abort();
    }

    ofs << "placeholder_data";
}

int main()
{
    write_to_file();

    return 0;
}
```

I'm relatively new to C++, so I have no idea why this would happen! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please put all relevant code into the question.

Comment: Before posting any questions on stackoverflow.com, everyone should take the [tour], read the [help], understand all the requirements for a [mre] and [ask] questions here. Not doing any of this results in a poor quality question almost every time. It then gets downvoted, closed, and then deleted. Repeated low-quality questions may result in a temporary ban from asking new questions.

Comment: at a guess you're using relative paths and the file isn't in the right folder relative to the working directory of the executable

Comment: @AlanBirtles What do you mean by relative paths?

Comment: @Evg Sorry - fixed that! :)

Comment: Have you checked the contents of `str_path` in a debugger?

Comment: Nothing was "fixed". Pop quiz: if you cut/paste this ***exactly as shown***, into a new empty file, and try to compile it, what do you think will happen? Try that.

Comment: @Evg Yep - it held: <C:\\Users\\Weharn\\source\\repos\\harmonic.series\\harmonic.series\\x64\\Release\\harmoinc.series.wav>, which I believe is where the debugger is run from in release mode.

Comment: and is that the correct path?

Comment: You could try enabling exceptions for `ofstream` and checking the exception message.

Comment: Btw, `std::filesystem::path(path).replace_filename("harmonic_series.wav")` will do the job without any for loops and hard-coded constants.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Is this better?

Comment: @Evg How do I enable exceptions for ofstream? Like I said, I'm new to this - sorry!

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/exceptions (You need to enable exceptions first and only then call `std::ofstream::open` explicitly.)

Comment: @Evg I just tried using std::filesystem::path(path).replace_filename("harmonic_series.wav") as you suggested, but I got an error saying "incomplete type not allowed"

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/j19b9WY6a - A simple example. On my machine I get error code 3 (`ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND`). It looks like MS STL doesn't put anything useful into the exception message, so you could just examine `GetLastError()` in the `if` branch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everybody who contributed for helping out! It turns out that in the release configuration, the empty wchar_t array isn't initialised with as the value 52428 ('쳌'), but as as mostly '\0'. Because in the debug configuration the '\0' terminator only came up exactly once (at the end of the path) before the remainder of the array was '쳌', my for loop break condition didn't work when there was more than one '\0'. The following fixed the issue:

```
    /*earlier code */ GetModuleFileName(NULL, path, 256);                             //finds the current path

    for (int i{}; (i < 256 && i != path_terminus && path[i - 1] != '\0'); ++i)     //finds location of the end of the path within the string
    {
        if (path[i] == '\0')
        {
            path_terminus = i;
        }
    }

    for (int i{ 0 }; i < (path_terminus - 36); ++i)         //deletes the "\\harmonic.series.exe" from the end
    {
        str_path.push_back(path[i]);
    } /* later code */
```

However, following @Evg's excellent suggestion about std::filesystem::path (which I didn't even know existed!), I replaced everything from the start of write_to_file() with the following:

```
/*earlier #includes*/
#include <filesystem>

void write_to_file()
{
    wchar_t cpath[256];

    GetModuleFileName(NULL, cpath, 256);                             //finds the current path

    std::filesystem::path path(cpath);

    path.replace_filename("harmonic series troubleshooting doc.txt");

    std::ofstream ofs(path, std::ios::binary);          //opens the filestream

    if (!ofs.is_open())
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to open the ofstream.\n\n";
        system("pause");
        std::abort();
    }

    ofs << "placeholder_data";
}
```

Which also works perfectly, is much more elegant, and takes up less space - all round a far better option.

Side note (and I didn't know about this either), when you set your compiler standard (i.e. C++14, C++17 etc.), it only applies to your current configuration. This meant that what I was doing in Release was only using C++14, not C++20 like the rest of my project. This may or may not have had an impact on my issue, but is worth keeping in mind.